# How to fix ProcessException while building APK after support libs update?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, gradle

I've upgraded to **support** libs *appcompat-v7* and *support-v4* to **22.1.1** (from *22.0.0*):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
```

And now I've started getting **ProcessException** while building APK:

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

And such errors at Jenkins:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_stagingDebugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         workspace:app:1.5.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         workspace:app:1.5.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         workspace:app:1.5.1 > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         workspace:app:1.5.1 > com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.1.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         workspace:app:1.5.1 > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         workspace:app:1.5.1 > com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         workspace:app:1.5.1 > com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.3.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.pom
         file:/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.1.1/support-v4-22.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         workspace:app:1.5.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Still the same after downgrading Java to 1.7:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexStagingDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

How should I force Jenkins to download exact version of support libs?

#### Update

I'm using this command line on Jenkins:

```
sudo /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-support
```

And I get this output:

```
...
Downloading Android Support Library, revision 22.1.1
Installing Android Support Library, revision 22.1.1
Installed Android Support Library, revision 22.1.1
...
```

But then doing

```
./gradlew clean aSD
```

I'm still getting same error.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and updating of `extra-android-m2repository` has solved it. You can do the update as follows:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
```

Answer (score 2):

Update AppCompat v7 from Android SDK Manager. For me it has been fixed after updating it :)

Comment: I've added update for the question... The problem still exist. I have udate latest support lib, but somehow it's not being found or what...

Answer (score 2):

I had to update my gradle from 1.0.1 in build.gradle:

```
    `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution in my case was to ensure that in the Android SDK Manager the component "Android Support Repository" is installed, in my case revision 14 is the current one.

Comment: That was my problem too. The support library setup webpage says: "Note: If you're developing with Android Studio, select and install the Android Support Repository item instead". I had no problem with android studio though, but I did using 'gradlew' manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-support
```

will update the SDK but also set the permissions of the downloaded sdk's to root user. You need to change it to Jenkins user or do a chmod 755 on the directory.

Answer (score 0):

i just updated all google libs and it solved my problem

> android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter     "extra-android-m2repository,    extra-android-support,    extra-google-admob_ads_sdk,    extra-google-analytics_sdk_v2,    extra-google-google_play_services_froyo,    extra-google-google_play_services,    extra-google-m2repository,    extra-google-play_apk_expansion,    extra-google-play_billing,    extra-google-play_licensing,    extra-google-webdriver"